# get day from date with append 0 in 1 to 9 digit

Tags: shell-script, awk, hp-ux

i am using awk command to get creation date of file and from that i m fetching day,month and year but for 1-9 digit i am getting output like **2016041** but i want output **20160401**.

```
D=$(ls -ltr $line | awk '{print $7}') 

M=$(ls -ltr $line | awk '{print $6}')

 Y=$(date +"%Y")

TEMP2="$Y$M$D"
```

Comment: stat is not possible because of HP-UX

Comment: There is no _creation date_. You're retrieving _last modification date_.

Comment: Agree - but OP probably wants what he sees :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this properly from `ls` is awkward because the date format changes with the age of the files.  Furthermore, the computation for `$M` is suspect since `ls` normally returns a name for the month rather than a number. Presumably OP is using the `date` command to attempt to work around the differences in `ls` date format, but that means that all of the files would get the same value for a year.

However, OP's question is focused on leading zeros.  *That* part is easy in `awk`:

```
D=$(ls -ltr $line | awk '{printf "%02d", $7}')
M=$(ls -ltr $line | awk '{printf "%02d", $6}')
Y=$(date +"%Y")
```

If I had to do this on HPUX, I would look into using Perl (which is preinstalled), since that can avoid the problems with `ls` and date format.

Here is a quick example ([`man perlfunc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) is where to start):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

for my $n ( 0 .. $#ARGV ) {
    my (
        $dev,  $ino,   $mode,  $nlink, $uid,     $gid, $rdev,
        $size, $atime, $mtime, $ctime, $blksize, $blocks
    ) = stat( $ARGV[$n] );
    my ( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst ) =
      localtime($mtime);

    # printf "%s:", $ARGV[$n];
    printf "%04d%02d%02d", 1900 + $year, 1 + $mon, $mday;

    # printf "\n";
}
1;
```

I checked the script with the two `printf` statements uncommented, and looking at sample files.  You would call this script with just one filename (for multiple filenames, the lack of formatting would be a nuisance).

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how can i use perl to get date ?

Comment: @ChiragDhaduk that's what this answer shows you!

Answer (score 0):

Leading zeros may also be added using `printf`. [It seems to be available](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/hp-ux/man1/printf.1.html) in HP-UX.

```
D=$(ls -ltr $line | awk '{print $7}') 
M=$(ls -ltr $line | awk '{print $6}')
Y=$(date +"%Y")
TEMP2="`printf '%02d%02d%04d' $D $M $Y`"
```